# How do I check whether a variable was changed?

Tags: python

Say I have two lists

```
[['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '3'], ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'G']]
```

In this case each index matches the number on the left with the letter on the right, so 1 : A, and 2 : G and so on. I want to see if AT LEAST one number on the left changes mapping. So, I want to know if ANY number changes mapping. So if 1 : A changes to 1 : T, I would have True returned.

Comment: Not sure what does this mean "In this case each index matches the number on the left with the letter on the right"

Comment: essentially i want one to one relations between the elements on the left and the elements on the right. so here the relations would be 1 : A, 2: G, 1 : T, 3 : 1, 1 : T, 3 :G. this is what i mean by "index" within the lists.

Comment: Can we have a bit more context? How and when is the mapping likely to change? Could you detect it as it is being changed? Can you save a copy just before it may change and compare it right after it may have changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary:

```
s = [['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '3'], ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'G']]
new_s = {b:a for a, b in zip(*s)}
final_vals = [a for a, b in new_s.items() if any(d == b for c, d in new_s.items() if c != a)]
```

Output:

```
['A', 'T']
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually perform the assignments in a dictionary, stop whenever one changes an existing entry.

```
def check_overwrite(keys, values):
    d = {}
    for k,v in zip(keys, values):
        if d.setdefault(k, v) != v:
            return True
    return False

print check_overwrite(['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '3'], ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'G'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if it's not only changed but what changed this (stolen from above) should help

```
>>> numbers = ['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '3']
>>> letters = ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'G']

>>> def check_overwrite(keys, values):
...     d = {}
...     overlap = {}
...     for k,v in zip(keys, values):
...         if d.setdefault(k, v) != v:
...             overlap[k] = v
...     return overlap
...
>>> check_overwrite(numbers, letters)
{'1': 'T', '3': 'G'}
```